# Why aren't my files being found?

Tags: python, node.js, docker

I'm looking to build assets needed for my front end in a docker container and then serve them through a python framework. Everything seems to work as expected until python tries to locate the files, which results in a FileNotFoundError. If I attach to the container and attempt the same command, the files are found with no trouble. Why does python fail to find the files initially?

---

**index.js** (Snipped) - build destination set to `/alpine/dist`

```
// Template for index.html
index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist/index.html'),  // /alpine/dist

// Paths
assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist'),  // /alpine/dist
```

**app.py** (Snipped) - read list of files from directory `/alpine/dist` (`['index.html']` expected)

```
from alpine.utils import get_base_path, listfiles
logger.info(os.path.join(get_base_path(), 'dist'))  # /alpine/dist
logger.info(listfiles(os.path.join(get_base_path(), 'dist')))  # /alpine/dist
```

**utils.py** (Snipped)

```
import os

def listfiles(path):
    return [_ for _ in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, _))]

def get_base_path():
    current_directory_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    base_path = os.path.split(os.path.split(current_directory_path)[0])[0]
    return base_path
```

---

**Dockerfile** (Snipped) - build static assets in /alpine/dist, print file structure, and launch script as alpine user (created in snipped portion)

```
ENV INSTALL_PATH /alpine
ENV ALPINE_USER alpine
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' $ALPINE_USER

RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY js js
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH/js
RUN npm run build
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY . .

RUN echo $INSTALL_PATH
RUN ls -la $INSTALL_PATH
RUN echo $INSTALL_PATH/dist
RUN ls -la $INSTALL_PATH/dist

CMD sudo -u $ALPINE_USER python manage.py api run
```

**docker-compose.yml** (Snipped)

```
services:
  api:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - '.:/alpine'
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:10'
    volumes:
      - './tmp/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
```

---

**docker-compose up --build** (Snipped) - /alpine/dist exists and contains expected assets, but python fails to see them at same path

```
Step 25/29 : RUN echo $INSTALL_PATH
/alpine

Step 26/29 : RUN ls -la $INSTALL_PATH
total 80
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Feb  8 15:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 85 root root  4096 Feb  8 15:14 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1026 Feb  8 15:13 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     0 Aug 17 06:06 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     0 Aug 17 06:04 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb  8 15:14 config
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb  8 04:22 dist
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   379 Feb  8 15:13 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root  4096 Feb  7 19:20 js
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   319 Oct  2 19:19 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Oct 10 19:01 migrations
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root  4096 Jan  9 16:31 alpine
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   738 Feb  7 17:04 requirements.txt

Step 27/29 : RUN echo $INSTALL_PATH/dist
/alpine/dist

Step 28/29 : RUN ls -la $INSTALL_PATH/dist
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Feb  8 04:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 Feb  8 15:14 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  504 Feb  8 04:22 index.html
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Feb  8 04:22 static

Step 29/29 : CMD sudo -u $ALPINE_USER python manage.py api run
api_1       | 2018-02-08 15:14:26,601 - alpine.app/_init_sanic - INFO - /alpine/dist
api_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
api_1       |   File "manage.py", line 19, in <module>
api_1       |     cli()
api_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
api_1       |     return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
api_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
api_1       |     rv = self.invoke(ctx)
api_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
api_1       |     return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
api_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
api_1       |     return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
api_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
api_1       |     return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
api_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
api_1       |     return callback(*args, **kwargs)
api_1       |   File "/alpine/alpine/cli/api.py", line 55, in run
api_1       |     app = AlpineApp(config_path=config_path)
api_1       |   File "/alpine/alpine/app.py", line 80, in __init__
api_1       |     self._init_sanic()
api_1       |   File "/alpine/alpine/app.py", line 89, in _init_sanic
api_1       |     logger.info(listfiles(os.path.join(get_base_path(), 'dist')))
api_1       |   File "/alpine/alpine/utils/__init__.py", line 42, in listfiles
api_1       |     return [_ for _ in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, _))]
api_1       | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/alpine/dist'
alpine_api_1 exited with code 1
```

**docker run -it alpine_api sudo -u alpine python manage.py api run** (Snipped) - when attaching to container after, files are found as expected

```
2018-02-08 15:34:34,920 - alpine.app/_init_sanic - INFO - /alpine/dist
2018-02-08 15:34:34,921 - alpine.app/_init_sanic - INFO - ['index.html']
[2018-02-08 15:34:35 +0000] [1] [INFO] Goin' Fast @ http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: What do you expect `volumes:      - '.:/alpine'` to do?

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: someone who understands what the issue was (or @nickles) should put this as answer. I do not understand what fixed it.